# Google App Engine (Flex) use express sever alongside separate socket.io server

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm feeling really stupid about that, but here's my problem.

I'm using Socket-Controller and routing-controller in the same NodeTS App. Therefore i needed to create two express servers. One is listening to port 3000 or whatever the env is, and the other on port 65080. Locally, this works perfect. Now on GAE, my HTTP Server for the normal requests is working, while my SocketServer always times out.

If it helps, here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
    instances: 1
resources:
    cpu: .5
    memory_gb: 0.5
    disk_size_gb: 10

network:
    session_affinity: true
    forwarded_ports:
        - 65080

env_variables:
    APP_NAME: Backend
    APP_SCHEMA: https
    APP_HOST: localhost
    APP_PORT: 3000
    APP_ROUTE_PREFIX: /api
    APP_BANNER: true
    TYPEORM_CONNECTION: postgres
    TYPEORM_USERNAME: postgres
    TYPEORM_DATABASE: db
    TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE: true
    TYPEORM_LOGGING: error
    TYPEORM_LOGGER: advanced-console
```

And i am creating the SocketServer with that:

```
import {MicroframeworkLoader, MicroframeworkSettings} from 'microframework-w3tec';

import {createSocketServer} from 'socket-controllers';

import {env} from '../env';

export const socketLoader: MicroframeworkLoader = (settings: MicroframeworkSettings | undefined) => {
    if (!settings) {
        return;
    }
    const io = createSocketServer(65080, {
        controllers: env.app.dirs.controllers,
        middlewares: env.app.dirs.middlewares,
    });
    settings.setData('socket_io', io);
};
```

By the way, i am using [this](https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate) boilerplate.

Help is appreciated, since this is getting me frustrated. :)

EDIT: Creating an second microservice is not really an option, since they are sharing too much to be isolated from each other. (Services, DB Models, Settings).

EDIT: I configured the firewall with this:

```
    --allow tcp:65080 \
    --target-tags websocket \
    --description "Allow websocket traffic on port 65080"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution was rather easy.

I needed to bind the Socket Server to the same HTTP Server instance, which express is using. Below are my changes.

socketLoader.ts

```
const io = require('socket.io')(settings.getData('express_server'));

    useSocketServer(io, {
        controllers: env.app.dirs.controllers,
        middlewares: env.app.dirs.middlewares,
    });
```

Where express_server is the server instance returned by expressApp.listen(env.app.port).

Comment: may i ask you when do you call sovketLoader in your loaders-array in app.js? i have the issue that the server is starting without errors but i can’t connect to the socket. i think it's because i have to call useSocketServer before expressApp.listen().
EDIT: i'm using the same boilerplate

Comment: figured it out! if anybody else has the same problem: use socket.io version 2.X or enable allowEIO3: true, in version 3.X and call socketLoader after expressLoader in app.ts